# how to Transform related variables into independent variables

Tags: r

I want to Transform related variables into independent variables.

```
   xiangguan<-function(y){
  r1=pnorm(y[1])
  ux1=r1
  x[1]=qnorm(ux1,meanx[1],sigmax[1])

  r2=pnorm(y[2])
  ux2=***hinverse(copula1,r2,ux1)***
  x[2]=qnorm(ux2,meanx[2],sigmax[2])

  r3=pnorm(y[3])
  hdie=h(copula1,ux1,ux2)
  ux3=hinverse(copula2,hinverse(copula5,r3,hdie),ux1)
  x[3]=qnorm(ux3,meanx[3],sigmax[3])

  r4=pnorm(y[4])
  h1=hinverse(copula8,r4,r3)
  h2=hinverse(copula6,h1,hdie)
  ux4=hinverse(copula3,h2,ux1)
  x[4]=qnorm(ux4,meanx[4],sigmax[4])

  r5=pnorm(y[5])
  h3=hinverse(copula10,r5,r4)
  h4=hinverse(copula9,h3,r3)
  h5=hinverse(copula7,h4,hdie)
  ux5=hinverse(copula4,h5,ux1)
  x[5]=qnorm(ux5,meanx[5],sigmax[5])
  return(x)
}
```

in the code，I want input mixture copula （3 components copula）in hinverse（copula，u，v）or h（copula，u，v） but in this function copula only input an object components ,could you help me? you are my god ! thank you! salute！

Comment: in line 6 ,the ***  is redundant， it's my careless

Comment: Why do you want to get uncorrelated variables?

Comment: I want to do a reliability analysis, so I have to transform the correlated variables into uncorrelated variables for analysis

Comment: Can you give me your email？I'll send you the complete program

Comment: for example： in pure copula   only one object ： copula1 <- normalCopula(par=0.7)                                        now   I want to input  mixture  copula：it  have 3 copula object                                                               copula11<-surClaytonCopula(par=fit$output$bicop_param[5,4,1])
copula12<-BB8Copula(par=fit$output$bicop_param[5,4,2])
copula13<-r90BB8Copula(par=-fit$output$bicop_param[5,4,3])

Comment: I am not sure if giving my email is eligible here on this website. I see you try to transfer the data using `qnorm` is that correct? if yes, please let me know.

Comment: For transforming the data into uncorrelated one needs the CDF of the vine copula. To the best of my knowledge, the VineCopula function does not have this.

Comment: qnorm is right, because my data is norm distribution，if  weibull distribution，it is qweibull  ，if lognormal distribution ，it  is qlnorm， so on ，this is no problem.

Comment: I will upload my program on a new question. you  can  see it ,thanks! my friend